# How to parse objects inside a Javascript array and render using React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Im making an API call where I get the response as follows:

```
{  
  "meta":
  {  
    "code":200,
    "msg":"xyz"
  },
  "data":[
           {"name": "Test1"},
           {"name": "Test2"},
         ]
}
```

I have looked at other answers but Im unable to figure out how to parse this in my React application.

My table body is as follows:

```
   <tbody>
        { this.props.names && this.props.names.map(this.names)}
    </tbody>
```

The function is as follows:

```
names(data) {
const name = data.name;
const id = data.id;
  return (
    <tr key={name}>
      <td> {name} </td>
      <td> {id} </td>
    </tr>
 );
}
```

Im passing the response data from the API call as props to the table.
The problem is Im the table is just blank though the response contains the data as shown above.

Comment: Can you post how exactly and where you are passing the data to the props? I suspect you are not properly waiting for the async fetch call to finish

Comment: Yes you were right. The props werent passed properly. 
Since your response is a comment I dont know how to select this as the answer.

Comment: It's okay, no need to. You can delete your question or post your own answer for the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution as pointed out by @Raul Rene was right. 
The props which were being passed down were incorrect.
In my  `mapStateToProps` the return was wrong due to which the above parsing was failing.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right I believe you should do something like this:

```
fetchData() {
  ...
  // fetch the JSON
  const result = {  
    "meta": {  
      "code":200,
      "msg":"xyz"
    },
    "data": [
      {"name": "Test1", "id": 1},
      {"name": "Test2", "id": 2},
    ]
  }
  this.setState({ data: result.data });
}

parseData(data) {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {data.map(({name, id}, idx) => {
        <tr key={`row_${idx}`}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{name}</td>
        </tr>
      })}
    </tbody>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.parseData(this.state.data)}
    </div>
  );
}
```